# Promises not working on IE11

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, bluebird, es6-promise

I'm new to Promises on javascript so I hope some can help me with this issue.

**Problem:** Promise not being execute on IE11, works fine on Chrome and FireFox

**Frameworks used:** I tried using es6-promise.d.ts and bluebird.d.ts same result.

Code:

```
static executeSomething(): Promise<any> 
{
  console.log("inside executeSomething");
  var test= new Promise((resolve, reject)=>
  {
     console.log("inside Promise");

  }).catch(function(error){console.log("error")}); 
 console.log("after promise"); 
 return test;      
}
```

**Results:** on chrome and Firefox I can see all the logs but on IE11 I only see "Inside executeSomething" which means the problem is while creating the promise.

I thought it was because IE11 didn't support es6 but I get the same result using bluebird, I hope some can bring some light to my issue.

Comment: IE11 does not support es6 promises. https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#ie11

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to include a promise polyfill in your page for IE11 to work.

Your instinct to use es-promise is correct, but you need to also include the `.js` file in your html

```
<script src="path/to/es6-promise.js"></script>
```

The `.d.ts` file will give the TypeScript compiler it's definitions, but does not affect runtime. You still need to include the polyfill in your html for it to actually run in the browser.

The biggest thing to remember when using TypeScript or any compiled language is the difference between *compile* time and *run* time.

`.d.ts`, `.ts`, `.tsx`, etc. Are all **compile** time files. Which means that these are not the files that are actually executed, but instead the files that generate the runtime code.

`.js` files are the **runtime** files. These are the files that are run by the browser.

`.d.ts` files do *not* contain code, but instead a definition of the code's signature and therefore should *always* be accompanied with a corresponding `.js` file that will run in the browser.

Comment: es6-promise is a terrible promise polyfill for what it's worth.

Comment: Thanks!!! this only happens on IE not sure why but adding the reference solved my problem.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, do you have a suggestion for a better polyfill?

Comment: I hear lie.js is pretty good, but I stick with bluebird mostly. Even the core-js polyfill is nice.